# Sum of $2008$ consecutive positive integers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, integers

> The sum of $2008$ consecutive positive integers is a perfect square. What is the
>   minimum value of the largest of these integers?

I understand this means that I need the sum of numbers, where $n=2008$ and I believe that the nearest perfect square might be $1936$ or $2025$. Am I correct? Then, I can equate the sum of $n$ numbers formula to the sum and find the first number in the series, which should be the minimum value, I believe!

Comment: Consider first the sum of $2008$ consecutive integers, starting from $k$. Can you come up with an expression for the value of the sum? as in 
$$ S(k) = (k) + (k +1) + (k +2) + \dots + (k +2007) + (k + 2008) = \dots $$

Comment: @MattiP. Adding $(k + 2008)$ would make it a sum of $2009$ consecutive integers, no?

Comment: @an4s Ah, true. Well, the idea is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Sum of $2008$ consecutive integers equal to a perfect square can be written as
$$n + (n + 1) + (n + 2) + \cdots + (n + 2007) = 2008n + \sum_{i = 1}^{2007}i = x^2$$
You want to find a value of $x$ such that $$\dfrac{x^2 - \sum_{i = 1}^{2007}i}{2008}$$ is an integer.

Comment: Yes, I am trying this way now. Thank You an4s!   :-)

Comment: I believe also that, x should be a multiple of 4?

Comment: I considered x as a multiple of 2; and by applying the formula, as above; I got the lowest integer to be 126.   Am I correct?   :-S

Comment: Yes, I got $126$ using MATLAB as well.

Comment: Thank You an4s. I used Excel. However, is there a manual way to get the answer without using software?..   :-S

Answer (score 0):

The sum is:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{2007} (n+k)=x^2 \Rightarrow 2008n+1004\cdot 2007=x^2.$$
Note that $x=2k$. Then:
$$502n+251\cdot 2007=k^2 \Rightarrow 251\cdot (2n+2007)=k^2.$$
Since $251$ is a prime number, then $k=251m$. Then:
$$2n+2007=251m^2.$$
The smallest $m=3$ and $n=126$. Hence, the minimum of the largest of them is $126+2007=2133$.

Comment: Ok, I am a bit confused here, is the answer 126 or 2133?

Comment: $n=126$ is the first and $n+2007=2133$ is the last number of the $2008$ consecutive positive integers. The question is asking to find the minimium of the largest of the $2008$ numbers, so the final answer is $2133$.

Comment: Thanks @farruhota !..that solves my confusion.   :-)

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck.